# how to get unity environment in gnome

Tags: unity, gnome

I don't want to remove gnome shell but at the same time I want to unity desktop also can I get it done in my pc with pre-installed gnome 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only done the reverse (install gnome-shell when Unity is already installed) - but it should work in a similar way, as far as I know:

`sudo apt-get install unity lightdm`

LightDM is the login manager, and when you boot the machine, it should allow you to select the window manager you use on the login screen. This has worked for me when installing Gnome-shell on an Ubuntu machine which already had Unity installed, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: it didnt worked

Comment: Is it booting directly into gnome-shell?

Comment: i cant get the unity environment option itself in lightdm

Comment: It may appear to be 'hidden' - is there no circle to the right of the login name that you can click on to select unity or gnome?

Comment: yes it is but shows only 3 options like GNOME , GNOME [cairo dock] and GNOME CLASSIC

Comment: Try and install the 'ubuntu-desktop' meta package perhaps? `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`